# Illegal forward reference error for static final fields

Tags: java, javac, forward-declaration

I'm trying to compile a Java class which `javac` rejects with an *illegal forward reference* error, where the offending reference is lexically *after* the referenced field. The following class is stripped down as much as possible while showing the same behavior:

`java.util.concurrent.Callable` and the many uses of `Object` are just used as placeholders to remove irrelevant pieces of code.

```
public class Test {
    static final Object foo = method(new java.util.concurrent.Callable<Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object call() throws Exception {
            return bar;
        }
    });

    static final Object bar = foo;

    static Object method(Object binder) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

When compiled using `javac Test.java`, javac prints the following error message:

```
Test.java:9: illegal forward reference
    static final Object bar = foo;
                              ^
```

So the compiler complains about `bar`'s declaration referencing `foo` while `foo` should be in the scope of `bar`'s declaration. But as soon as the reference of `bar` in `foo`'s declaration is removed, e.g. by changing line 5 from `return bar;` to `return null;`, the class is accepted by the compiler.

How can this be explained? Is my understanding of *forward* as meaning *lexically after* wrong or is this some special case I'm not aware of?

Comment: I can confirm that javac from Sun's JDK 1.6.0_29 rejects this as described; Eclipse Indigo compiles this without a complaint. You have found a bug in either javac or Eclipse - congratulations!

Comment: Note that you can remove the method `method`, and assign the new `Callable` directly to `foo`, and get the same error.

Comment: I think this is a bug in javac, although i'm not enough of a language lawyer to be certain. I note that you can work around it by writing `bar = Test.foo`.

Comment: gcj 4.4.3 also compiles this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your understanding of *forward reference* is correct. The reference to `foo` on line 9 isn't a *forward reference* at all since it doesn't appear textually before its declaration (see the definition of what constitutes a *forward reference* in section 8.3.2.3 of [The Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/download/langspec-3.0.pdf)).

The behavior you observe is a symptom of a javac **bug**. See [this bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6676362). The problem appears to be fixed in newer versions of the compiler, e.g. [OpenJDK 7](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/langtools/rev/6542933af8f4).

It only affects *forward references* used as initializers to **final** fields. The issue appears to affect static and non-static fields equally.

Note that the reference to `bar` in `call()` is a legal *forward reference* since it occurs inside a different class (see examples in section 8.3.2.3 of [The Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/download/langspec-3.0.pdf)).

Also, note that each of the following alterations make the error disappear:

Making `bar` non-final:

```
static Object bar = foo;
```

Initializing `bar` in static or instance initializer block:

```
static final Object bar;

static {
  bar = foo;
}
```

Moving the initialization of `foo` to an initializer block also helps.

Initializing `bar` from a non-final temporary reference to `foo`:

```
static Object tmp = foo;
static final Object bar = tmp;
```

Initializing `bar` with `Test.foo` (found by Tom Anderson) or with `this.foo` in non-static case:

```
static final Object bar = Test.foo;
```

Removing `bar` and referring to the object using `foo` inside `call()`:

```
static final Object foo = method(new java.util.concurrent.Callable<Object>() {
    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        return foo;
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Java Language Specifications](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#287406) specifically mentions restrictions on object fields during the initializations phase, specifically (*C* is an interface or class):

A compile-time error for forward references occurs when these conditions are fulfilled:

> - The usage occurs in an instance (respectively static) variable initializer of *C* or in an instance (respectively static) initializer of *C*.
> - The usage is not on the left hand side of an assignment.
> - The usage is via a simple name.
> - C is the innermost class or interface enclosing the usage.

The article [What are the forward reference rules?](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-are-the-forward-reference-rules/9) contains an excellent explanation of the rules and the restrictions when it comes to initializing members and forward referencing.

Comment: The relevant passage of the JLS is [8.3.2.3 Restrictions on the use of Fields during Initialization](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#287406).

Comment: I fail to see how that answers the question? For the assignment `bar = foo` these conditions are met, which means that `foo` must be declared textually before `bar` - which it is. On the other hand, for the usage `return bar`, the last condition is not met, and therefore no constraint imposed on the order of declaration.