# Cannot reference a field before it is defined, but only if you don't qualify it

Tags: java, initialization, syntax-error

I found happening with the following code made my jaw drop:

```
public class MCVE {

    { // instance initializer
        System.out.println(test); // cannot reference a field before it is defined
        System.out.println(this.test);
    }
    private final String test = "wat";
}
```

The line `System.out.println(test);` is giving the error

> Cannot reference a field before it's defined.

But the line `System.out.println(this.test);` is **not**

#### Why does this not error when I qualify it?

Comment: The problem is not specific to lambdas, an instance initializer will have the same problem. A normal constructor however will not have this issue. You can change `private final Runnable r = () -> {` to `{` and will face the same behaviour.

Comment: there is no constructor involved ... what point are you trying to make?

Comment: You can also change the Runnable lambda to a String field: `private final String test2 = test;` produces the same result (`String test2 = this.test;` works)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820302/recursive-initializer-works-when-i-add-this

Comment: Still a little confused: will it print "wat" or "" in case we delete the unqualified line and run the lambda? Ah I see, as Matt is pointing out http://ideone.com/kGO82z. I guess I was confused with how C++ does it which gives you control on whether this or test would be captured (by value, etc.).

Comment: @ChristopherOezbek it will print "wat" correctly. final Strings are considered Constant values and are initialized before final Reference-Typed fields. The declaration order is not important for that. Also qualified names will be resolved to the interned String that's created for every hardcoded string on class-load

Comment: Matt's link indicates otherwise ("" printed) for the lambda case, not your updated answer.

Comment: @ChristopherOezbek the link in mat's comment on his answer as well as the link in your comment print me `wat` to stdout... then again mat's link doesn't use lambdas..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with so many of these questions, it's because [the JLS says so.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.2.3)

> #### 8.3.2.3 Restrictions on the use of Fields during Initialization
>
> The declaration of a member needs to appear textually before it is used only if the member is an instance (respectively `static`) field of a class or interface C and all of the following conditions hold:
>
> - The usage occurs in an instance (respectively `static`) variable initializer of C or in an instance (respectively `static`) initializer of C.
> - The usage is not on the left hand side of an assignment.
> - The usage is via a simple name.
> - C is the innermost class or interface enclosing the usage.
>
> **It is a compile-time error if any of the four requirements above are not met.**

In your (failing) example, the "simple name" case is the condition not met. Qualifying the usage (with `this`) is the loophole that resolves the compile-time error.

[Explained another way:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14625002/139010)

> The use of fields inside an initialization block before the line on which they are declared can only be on the left hand side of an expression (i.e. an assignment), unless they are qualified (in your case `this.test`).

(paraphrased to suit this question more closely)

Comment: I agree that this is why it the unqualified instance does not work, but it is not correct why the qualified works. This is not a loophole, but rather it is not accessing test during initialization at all.

Comment: @ChristopherOezbek the qualified reference works specifically because the JLS says so.

Comment: And how would it work? What value would it access?

Comment: @ChristopherOezbek java is not an interpreted language.. I'd fare to say that is **is** accessed during initialization, since this is a little special, transforming "simple names" to "qualified names" and accordingly not falling under the accessing rule you seem to try here.

Comment: @ChristopherOezbek there is only one possible answer. http://ideone.com/kGO82z

Answer (score -3):

Because capturing `this` is possible at the time that you create the lambda. Capturing `test` is not (it is not yet defined). Later though, inside the lambda you can access `test` (via `this`).

Comment: The lambdas seem unrelated to this. When creating a new field before the lambda, accessing test in a qualified manner it also works.

Comment: No, the creation of the lambda causes a capture at the moment of creation. I do not follow a field should matter in this. You have a strict order in final and member initialization.

Comment: The lambda should capture `this` in both cases (assuming the other worked, which you can get by moving the declaration before the lambda).

Comment: As noted in two comments on the question: This problem is not specific to lambdas.

Comment: I guess I am misunderstanding the Lambda capture, which I assumed is a value capture at capture time and not via `this`.

Comment: For local variables, yes.