# Does the order in which methods are written matter?

Tags: java, android, syntax

I know that some programming languages require methods that are referenced/called by other methods to be declared before the caller in the code. For example:

```
private Method1(in){
  Return in *5;
}
Private Method2(paycheck){
  Return Method1(paycheck);
}
```

would be OK but,

```
Private Method1(paycheck){
  Return Method2(paycheck);
}
Private Method2 (in){
  Return in *5;
}
```

Would fail.

Is Java, and/or Android specific Java, one of these languages?

Comment: For methods, classes, no. For variables, still a yes. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14624919/illegal-forward-reference-java-issue

Comment: shouldn't be to hard to test....

Comment: Funny I looked first to see if this had been asked but that order of declaration one did not come up, I'd guess because i didn't use declaration  in my search....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, in Java and other Android languages (Kotlin, Dart) doesn't do compiling like C, it's okay to write methods or even variables anywhere inside the class.

Comment: But not in the method, which is still like C.